# Change background image source on button click in wpf forms

Tags: c#, wpf, image

My default background image is `"lobby.jpg`" and when I click the `"Lights"` button I want it to swap with `"lobby1.jpg"` and vice versa. These images are stored in `"obj\Debug\Images\"`.

Also I'd like to implement relative(?) imagesource uris so that I can access the images on any machine (without using the whole uri, just the `"obj\Debug\Images\"`).

Edit: So the main issue seems to be that I tried changing the window background without realising that it was getting "covered" by the grid background of the page. So what I did is I set the main window background to "lobby.jpg", I made the grid background invisible and used the code from the answer to swap between the 2 backgrounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use AppDomain basepath to exe (this is are simplest way)

```
var basePath= AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
var imageDirPath = $"{basePath}\\Images\\";
```

Example:

```
  bool clicked = false;
    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var basePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        var imageDirPath = $"{basePath}\\Images\\";
        if (clicked)
            image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imageDirPath+ "lobby.jpg"));
        else
            image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imageDirPath + "lobby1.jpg"));
        clicked = !clicked;
    }
```

Comment: So, where am I supposed to put those lines?

Comment: You can use this path when you want. For example, in "Lights" buttons event handler.  See my answer at top

Comment: This looks like it should work but I'm having some [problems](http://i.imgur.com/PsVpFKz.png) as it is right now.

Comment: "image" - your control name in GUI (in my example - Image control). You can use another control with another name. About string with $ - new feature in c# 6.0. You can use last framework, or change imageDirPath line to var imageDirPath = String.Format("{0}\\Images\\",basePath);

Comment: I'm now getting a DirectoryNotFoundException, I checked the imageDirPath and it is "basePath\\Images\" instead of "basePath\Images\" for some reason

Comment: You need to read some theory... try this... and use debugger
var imageDirPath = String.Format(@"{0}\Images\",basePath);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104923/discussion-between-xenofonos-and-user1576474).